# Kivy. Refreshing screen with different data

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

When I click on the button I need the data from the code to be shown on different screen. Below code does what I need despite that `Clock` adds widgets every second.   I would like the `TextInput` to be editable so when I type some value to the 'Row' it will stay as typed. I've tried to use `Clock.schedule_once()` but then the widgets does not appear. I've even tried something like below:

```
clock = 1
def fill_with_data(self, dt)
    if clock == 1: 
    for item ...
    clock +=1
```

witch locks adding new widgets (ridicules I know) but when I go back to `MainScreen` to show another data then it does not appear on the screen. Below you will find whole code.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv = """
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    ShowData:    

<DataSwitch>

    Button:
        text: 'Data 1'
        on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'
        on_press: root.show_data1()
    Button:
        text: 'Data 2'
        on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'
        on_press: root.show_data2()

<Row>
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30

<Rows>        
    orientation: 'vertical'

<MainScreen>   
    name: 'MainScreen'
    DataSwitch:

<ShowData>:
    name: 'ShowData'
    Rows:
    Button:
        text: 'Go back'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 20
        on_press: app.root.current = 'MainScreen'

"""

class Row(BoxLayout):
    text = ''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_text()

    def set_text(self):
        print('set', self.text)
        self.ids.text_input.text = self.text

class Rows(BoxLayout):

    data =[]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.fill_with_data()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.fill_with_data, 1)
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.fill_with_data)
    def fill_with_data(self, dt):
        for item in self.data:
            Row.text = item
            row = Row()
            self.add_widget(row)
            #self._rows[str(self.row_id)] = weakref.ref(row)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class DataSwitch(BoxLayout):

    data1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    data2 = ['5', '6', '7', '8']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DataSwitch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def show_data1(self):
        print('data1', self.data1)
        Rows.data = self.data1
        Rows()

    def show_data2(self):
        Rows.data = self.data2
        Rows()

class ShowData(Screen):
    pass

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the app will produce the following:

## Problem 1 - too many Rows instantiated

- `Rows:` as per kv file
- `Rows()` as per Python script in methods `show_data1()` and `show_data2()`. These `Rows` instances created does not have an associated `ModalView`.

## Problem 2 - switched screen before populating list, data

```
Button:
    text: 'Data 1'
    on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'
    on_press: root.show_data1()
Button:
    text: 'Data 2'
    on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'
    on_press: root.show_data2()
```

## Solution

The following example is just an illustration.

### kv file - Add `id: rows`

Add `id: rows` to `Rows:` in *class rule*, `<ShowData>:`. This will be use to reference attributes or methods in `class Rows()`.

### kv file - invoke `fill_with_data()`

Use `on_pre_enter` event of `Screen` and `Clock.schedule_once()` function to invoke method `fill_with_data()`

***Note***:
*`Row` will be added each time, the screen is displayed. In other words, `Row` widget will double each time. To prevent this, one might want to delete the widgets added in `on_pre_leave` event*.

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<ShowData>:
    name: 'ShowData'
    on_pre_enter:
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ids.rows.fill_with_data, 0.1)
    Rows:
        id: rows
```

### py file - Access attributes / methods in `class Rows()`

- Get object, `app` using `App.get_running_app()`
- Get object, `ShowData` using Screen Manager's `get_screen()` function e.g. `root.get_screen('ShowData')`
- Access attribute, `data` using `ids.rows.data`

#### Snippets

```
def show_data1(self):
    App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ShowData').ids.rows.data = self.data1

def show_data2(self):
    App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ShowData').ids.rows.data = self.data2
```

### Example

#### main.py

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

kv = """
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    ShowData:    

<DataSwitch>

    Button:
        text: 'Data 1'
        on_press: root.show_data1()
        on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'
    Button:
        text: 'Data 2'
        on_press: root.show_data2()
        on_press: app.root.current = 'ShowData'

<Row>:
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30

<Rows>:   
    orientation: 'vertical'

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'MainScreen'
    DataSwitch:

<ShowData>:
    name: 'ShowData'
    on_pre_enter:
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ids.rows.fill_with_data, 0.1)
    Rows:
        id: rows
    Button:
        text: 'Go back'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 20
        on_press: app.root.current = 'MainScreen'

"""


class Row(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, text, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.text_input.text = text


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    data = []

    def fill_with_data(self, dt):
        for item in self.data:
            row = Row(text=str(item))
            self.add_widget(row)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class DataSwitch(BoxLayout):
    data1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    data2 = ['5', '6', '7', '8']

    def show_data1(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ShowData').ids.rows.data = self.data1

    def show_data2(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ShowData').ids.rows.data = self.data2


class ShowData(Screen):
    def on_pre_leave(self):
        self.ids.rows.clear_widgets()


sm = Builder.load_string(kv)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: That's a lot of useful knowledge that even solved few more problems with my app. Really apreciate your help.

Comment: @ForyszeP consider accepting the answer as people put their time and effort to solve the problems.